# How on filter with spinner, setOnItemSelected in fragment

Tags: android, listview, spinner, adapter, android-cursor

i have `listfragment` with `cursor adapter`, and i want make `filter` for a listview (tasks, today, this week, .... (different is only in select with db, program is same) ) I have one problem.

How can i manage cursor adapter in `spinner.setOnItemSelected()` ? When i am trying fullfill `adapter` with `cursor` in `switch` in `setOnItemSelected`, i have many errors. I dont know how to write a `function`, then after selected from `spinner`, my `listview` will update with new select. This `setOnItemSelected` function is working, but how can i change log.v .... for a methods fullfilling `adapter` with other `selects`

```
public class PredmetFragment extends Fragment {

private DatabaseOp mDbHelper;
String username;
ListView listview;
View view;
TextView empty;
PredmetCursorAdapter adapter;

int item;
Spinner spinner;
Cursor predmetCursor;

public PredmetFragment() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.predmet_frag, container, false);

    listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listPredmet);
    empty = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.empty);
    spinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.p_spinner);

    mDbHelper = new DatabaseOp(getActivity());
    mDbHelper.open();

    showUserSettings(); 

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) 
        {
            item = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();

            switch (item)
            {
            case 0:
                Log.v ("Predmet item:", Integer.toString(item));
                predmetCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllPredmet(username, 1);
                break;
            case 1:
                Log.v ("Predmet item:", Integer.toString(item));
                predmetCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllPredmet1(username, 1);
                break;
            case 2:
                Log.v ("Predmet item:", Integer.toString(item));
                predmetCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllPredmet2(username, 1);
                break;
            case 3:
                Log.v ("Predmet item:", Integer.toString(item));
                predmetCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllPredmet3(username, 1);
                break;
            case 4:
                Log.v ("Predmet item:", Integer.toString(item));
                predmetCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllPredmet4(username, 1);
                break;
            case 5:
                Log.v ("Predmet item:", Integer.toString(item));
                predmetCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllPredmet5(username, 1);
                break;
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
        {

        }
    });

    final PredmetCursorAdapter adapter = new PredmetCursorAdapter(getActivity(), predmetCursor);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (listview.getCount()==0)
    {
        empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int stlpec, long arg3) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Cursor cur = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(stlpec);
            String odosli = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),PredmetShowerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(PredmetShowerActivity.ODOSLI, odosli);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            startActivityForResult(intent, 222);
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), odosli, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    mDbHelper.open();
    PredmetCursorAdapter adapter__ = (PredmetCursorAdapter)listview.getAdapter();

    Cursor predmetCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllPredmet(username, 1);
    adapter__.changeCursor(predmetCursor);
    adapter__.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();

    mDbHelper.open();
    PredmetCursorAdapter adapter__ = (PredmetCursorAdapter)listview.getAdapter();

    Cursor predmetCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllPredmet(username, 1);

    if (predmetCursor.getCount()==0)
    {
        empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    adapter__.changeCursor(predmetCursor);
    adapter__.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onPause() 
{
    super.onPause();
    mDbHelper.close();
}

public static PredmetFragment newInstance() {

    PredmetFragment f = new PredmetFragment();
    return f;
}

private void showUserSettings() 
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

    username = sharedPrefs.getString("prefUsername", "NULL");
}

}
```

Comment: you can put switch (pos) directly.post your log cat error if any

Comment: this is okay, but i need into switch get fullfilling cursor adapter, and i dont know how, allways show me a whole task without switch statements

Comment: u mean after selecting an item from spinner u need toad in listview right??

Comment: yes, after selecting, i need reload listview with data from other select

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
List<string> list=new arraylist<String>();
list.add(yourselectedSpinneritem);
ArrayAdapter adapter=new Arrayadapter(this,layout,list);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listview.setadapetr(adapter);
```